# Increment template.substitute variable on specified rules in a loop

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, python-2.7, templates

I have an issue than is invariably more complex that what I'm about to show, but it's concept will be similar:

I am writing 100's of new files, each name based on a specific datetime and they all have the same 'template'... I am using the 'string' library to build such a template.

```
with open(New_FileTemplate) as FileTemplate:
     FileTemplate = string.Template(FileTemplate.read())
```

(Yes I know I its bad coding practise for using the same names, but it's easier for showing my issue).

The simplified txt file template has the following form:

```
${datetime1} instruction1
${datetime2} instruction2
${datetime3} instruction3 ${StartLocation}
${datetime4} instruction4 ${StartOffset}
```

My StartLocation variable initially starts at 0 and ranges from 0 - 1000 and 
my StartOffset variable initially starts at 0 and ranges from 0-300

The StartLocation specifies which memory block and the StartOffset specifies where in the memory block to start. So once StartOffset reaches 300, then StartLocation then goes to value 1 and it's offset goes back to 0 etc...

Lets say I am trying to create 100 files with this template. For each file, the offset will increase by 10.

How can I incorporate this into my architecture?

I created a function:

```
def MemoryUsed(StartLocation, StartOffset):
    ImageSize = 10
    if StartOffset + ImageSize <=300:
        StartLocation = StartLocation
        StartOffset = StartOffset + ImageSize
        return StartLocation, StartOffset
    if StartOffset + ImageSize > 300:
        StartLocation +=1
        Offset = 0 + ImageSize
        return StartLocation, StartOffset
```

So this function will return a tuple of StartLocation and StartOffset

I then would write into the template as follows:

```
for i in range(1, 100):
    fout = open(DirectoryforFiles + 'filedate.txt' % filedate, 'w')
    fout.write(template.substitute(StartLocation=MemoryUsed(0, 0)[0], StartOffset=MemoryUsed(0,0)[1])
```

So this would initially write 0 to each variable for 100 files.. But I want it to increase after each file based on the rules outlined earlier!

I hope I've explained this ok?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK, so there are many problems with this.

- The most glaring is that `fout = open(DirectoryforFiles + 'filedate.txt' % filedate, 'w')` just overwrites the same file each time. `'filedate.txt' % filedate`, other than being outdated python, just throws an error.
- You call `MemoryUsed` twice per iteration which is unnecessary.
- [Python style](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names) dictates we name variables as `lowercase_with_underscores`, not `CapitalCase` which is used for classes!
- Don't use `string.Template`, it's a very outdated python feature. Use `str.format`.
- You never set `datetime1`, `datetime2`, etc. in the template.

For the loop, you want a double for loop:

```
file_number = 0
for offset in range(0, 301):
    for location in range(0, 1001):
        loc, off = memory_used(location, offset)  # renamed MemoryUsed
        with open('file{}.txt'.format(file_number), 'w') as fout:
             fout.write(template.substitute(StartLocation=loc, StartOffset=off))   
             # Although I'd replace with template.format(...)
```